# How to expose a static html page from ionic

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a static html page which intercept authorization message,  I'd like to expose this on the domain. It looks like so:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>JwtAuthDemo - Facebook Auth</title>  
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
    <script src="assets/util.js"></script>
  </head> 
  <body>
  <script>
      // if we don't receive an access token then login failed and/or the user has not connected properly
      var accessToken = getParameterByName("access_token");
      var message = {};
      if (accessToken) {
        message.status = true;
        message.accessToken = accessToken;
      }
      else
      {
        message.status = false;
        message.error = getParameterByName("error");
        message.errorDescription = getParameterByName("error_description");
      }
      window.opener.postMessage(JSON.stringify(message), "http://localhost:5000");
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I place this page next to the index.html page it is not exposed, however when I place it inside the assets folder it can be access.  I'm guessing I have to explicitly expose the page in one of the json config files however I'm not to sure how to do so?

I'd prefer not to have my redirect url be www.mydomain.com/assets/oauth-response-parser.html.  I'd like to keep this in my application seeing as it's part of the application.

How can I expose a static html page from Ionic as a sibling to the index.html page ?

Answer (score 0):

You can automatically get files to your assets directory by specifying that you want to run a custom script during your ionic builds. 
In your package.json you'd have a 'config' section where you can specify this script:

```
...
"config": {
    "ionic_copy": "./config/customCopy.config.js"
 },
...
```

and then your customCopy.config.js would contain an entry to copy over your html into assets:

```
module.exports = {
        copyAssets: {
        src: ['{{SRC}}/assets/**/*'],
        dest: '{{WWW}}/assets'
    }
}
```

More info on this process at the [ionic app scripts page](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts#custom-configuration)

I hope this steers you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want them in the asset directory, I want to include a static html file as a sibling to the index.html, so I can omit assets from the url